# Sending data packet from physical device to emulator

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-emulator

**What i am trying to accomplish:**

I've an app running on physical device and emulator, and it's listening to packets on tcp port 1027. I want to send packets from physical device to emulator.

**What I've already tried**

*host machine ip: 192.128.0.101*
*emulator serial number: emulator-5554*

Since emulator isn't directly connected to internet; it gets internet from its' host machine. So I tried sending the packet from my physical android to **192.128.0.101:1027**(host-machine-ip:port), and it didn't work. 
I did some research and tried : `adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:1027 tcp:1027` on my host-machine, then tried to send packet from physical device to **192.128.0.101:1027**, and that didnt work, instead i am getting this in logcat of my physical device:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.128.0.101 (port 1027): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

To solve this, I tried: `netcat -l -p 1027` on host machine, and got the error: `Error: Couldn't setup listening socket (err=-3)`

Comment: Through which medium you are sending packet from your android to host machine? through Wifi / Mobile Data or else? If you are sending packet through internet then an internal IP 192.128.X.X will not be visible/accessible. To reach to destination machine you have to send packet to your public IP and by using Port Forwarding you may redirect your packet to host machine. (Port forwarding can be configured by using your Router Setup page e.g. http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1 (depends on  routers)

Comment: I am sending packets from my physical android device to host machine using local ip address.